# Type Error cannot read property "Button" of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm getting the error: Type Error cannot read property "Button" of undefined
I've researched through google, however their solutions not helping me.

Here is how I declared an app.tsx file with **ThemeProvider** from Material Ui

```
 import {ThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
 .......
 return(
     <div className = {classes.app}>
         <ThemeProvider theme = {Theme} >
             <Router>
                 <Switch>
                     <Route exact path = '/'>
                         <Header />          
                     </Route>
                 </Switch>
             </Router>
         </ThemeProvider>
     </div>
```

So, before I was working on standard jsx, this kind of errors never appeared, it has started when I migrated to Type Script.
Here is the code of where I'm trying to declare Simple header

```
 return(
     <header className = 'header'>
         <Link to = '/'>
             <img alt = 'Logo' src = {Logo} />
         </Link>
         {Tabs.map(tabs => {return(
             <Button>
                 <h6>{tabs.Title}</h6>
             </Button>
             )}
         )}
     </header>
```

- 

I'm bit confused, because when I'm using standard HTML tags like

> button

it works, but is not working with Material Ui Components. Does it mean that I can not use Material Ui any more?

**As requested here is my Theme.tsx:**

```
import {createMuiTheme}  from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const Whitesmoke:string = "#f5f5f5";
const Whitecolor:string = "#808080";

export default createMuiTheme({
     palette: {
         primary:    { main: `${ Whitesmoke }` },
         secondary:  { main: `${ Whitecolor }` },
     },
});
```

Comment: Can you show how you  are importing the Button in your Header Component?

Comment: `import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';`

Comment: Hey Sabretooth, looks like this error is related to your theme object. Can you also add it so we can check it?

Comment: Is It possible that, I've missed something while installing React App with Typescript?

Comment: Hi @Sabretooth, i did some tests with your Theme and it all worked fine to me. Maybe you're getting this error due some `import` or some library version, hard to tell..